# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: sql, oracle

Facing error on the code execution :-

> ERROR at line 16: ORA-06550: line 16, column 5: PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case
>   declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select
>   update while with    << continue close current
>   delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute
>   commit forall merge pipe purge

Executed sql script with the below code as part of the script and facing error like below

```
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE orphansInconsistenDelProgress (currentTable VARCHAR(100), deletedCount INT, totalToDelete INT);
    INSERT INTO orphansInconsistenDelProgress (currentTable, deletedCount,totalToDelete) values ('',0,0);

   ALTER SESSION SET parallel_degree_policy = AUTO;
   ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML;
   COMMIT;
```

Comment: DDL statements are not allowed in the `PLSQL block`.
To execute the DDL statement in `PLSQL block`. Use `Execute immediate`

Comment: BEGIN

Stmt:=’ CREATE TABLE orphansInconsistenDelProgress (currentTable VARCHAR(100), deletedCount INT, totalToDelete INT)’;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  Stmt;

Stmt:=’ INSERT INTO orphansInconsistenDelProgress (currentTable, deletedCount,totalToDelete) values ('',0,0)’;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  Stmt;

Stmt:=’ IALTER SESSION SET parallel_degree_policy = AUTO’;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  Stmt;

Stmt:=’ ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML’;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  Stmt;

COMMIT;

Comment: Is this enough like above :-

Comment: This is slightly too much. "Insert into" is DML statement and can be used directly.

Comment: Yes, But why do you want to create the table in PLSQL Block? The table must be ready while using it in the PLSQL block. It is a bad practice of creating the table in PLSQL block. And yes, you can write DML statements directly in the PLSQL block.